# What is the usefulness of having more than one block initializer of the same kind in a class?

Tags: java

In Java, if there are more than one block initializers in a class, they are executed by the order they appear in the source code, which is identical to have just one initializer combining the sequence of statements in all the initializers of the same kind.

Consequently, what is the real need of having more than one block initializer of the same kind in a Java class? Please, provide useful examples.

Note: I know the practical usefulness of having one static or instance block initializer in a class, so no need to say that here.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide an example? I am not quiet sure what you are asking about? Are you talking about methods, variable, ponies?

Comment: @kkflf Instance blocks are just free-standing blocks (`{}`) in a class that are called when the class is instantiated, e.g. `class Foo { {//this is an initialization block} }`

Comment: The only value I see in having several is simply logical grouping. In other words, tidying up. "This block initializes all the physical properties, the next one shall initialize everything related to graphics, ..."

Comment: there is no need. Java allows it, and the programmer does as he or she pleases

Comment: If initialisers are in multiple "blocks", this has no effect whatsoever, i.e. everything would be the same if the blocks were combined into one single block.

Comment: @domdom You do not need several blocks for that, as you could do like this `class FooBar { { initPhysicalProps(); initGraphics(); } void initPhysicalProps() { ... } void initGraphics() { ... } // rest of class declarations }`.

Comment: Right, you don't *need* several blocks for that, but you *could* use several blocks for it. If the initialization is rather short and simple, it might be preferred. It comes down to taste. Personally, I've never used them at all.

Comment: Better organization possibly because initializers can appear anywhere in the code so they can be placed next to the method that's using them.

Comment: @domdom If the initialization is short and simple, then it can go inside a single constructor, or a single initialization block; no need for more than one. I come to believe that having more than one is not necessary, and having an instance initialization block, except for anonymous classes, is not necessary either. Hence,  instance initialization blocks are only needed for anonymous classes, and one is enough.

Answer (score -2):

Static initializer are called when the class if loaded the first time.

Regular initializer are called after the super class´ constructor is called and before the class constructor is executed.

Initializer is initialized based on the order they appear in. I.e. from top to bottom.

There is a good code example here:

http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/21/initialization-blocks-constructors-and-their-order-of-execution/

Comment: While technically correct, this is not an actual answer to OPs question (he explicitly stated *"I know the practical usefulness of having one static or instance block initializer in a class, so no need to say that here."*)

Comment: I just read the question again. I am very sorry about that. I had a brainfart, you clearly stating all of the above in your question. This is embarrassing.
The benefit from having multiple initializers are a way of obtaining high quality. You can devide your initializers into groups such that they can be placed next to the code which actually use those variables.